# Reading a specific sheet tab using Pandas Python off a XLS file

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I need to read the second tab(sheet two) only of the XLS file I have. I am able to read the file but it always gives the default 1st tab(sheet one). Below are the codes I wrote.

```
my_excel = pd.read_excel(r'c:\folder\file_name.xls , sheet_name = 'sheet two')
```

or

```
my_excel = pd.read_excel("c:\\folder\\file_name.xls" , sheet_name = 1)
```

I tried both ways but only shows data from Tab one(Sheet one = 0)
*Please note the type of the file is Microsoft excel 97-2003 worksheet(xls)

Comment: Can you show with a screenshot the names of your Excel worksheets (tabs) ?

Comment: A screenshot added to the question.

Comment: So `Swap Rate` is the tab you need to read as a dataframe, right ?

Comment: yes correct -  Swap Rate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure to use the latest version of pandas.
Rn this from your terminal :

```
pip install --upgrade pandas
```

Then, use [**`pandas.read_excel`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html#pandas.read_excel) to read a specific worksheet.

With either the worksheet's index :

```
my_excel = pd.read_excel(r"c:\folder\file_name.xls", sheet_name=1)
```

Or the worksheet's name:

```
my_excel = pd.read_excel(r"c:\folder\file_name.xls", sheet_name='Swap Rate')
```

Comment: Hi. That's exactly what I have done as shown in the question. I rechecked again but still it gives me data from sheet 1

Comment: No, this is not what you wrote in your question but still weird though! There is for sure a detail you're not telling us. Can you share a sample of your Excel file in Google docs ?

Comment: Yes, not exactly the same thing as I needed to simplify and understand the question. Unfortunately, the document is in a restricted environment. I tested out xlsx files and it all gives me the sheet one only. any other workaround as I need to capture data on 90 excel files to one excel.

Comment: Share any of the other dummy Excel files you say you've tested and we'll try to see what's going on.

Comment: I tested in the restricted environment only. have a look at the new updated image on the question to see if helps.

Comment: Try to restart your Jupyter notebook and then run your code in the same cell (not in separated one). It looks like you forgot to re-read your Excel file.

Comment: I tried it all. same output. I updated the image

Comment: I bet you're using an old pandas version. Run this on your terminal `pip install --upgrade pandas`. This will fix your problem for sure !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248351/discussion-between-abokey-and-dhakshika).

Comment: After upgrading this was sorted. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile('path_to_file.xls')
df = pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name = 'Your sheet name')
```

or

```
#df = pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name = None)
df = pd.read_excel('path_to_file.xls', sheet_name = None) # pandas will read all the sheets from an excel workbook by setting 

sheet_name = None


df["sheet name"] #will return a DataFrame from the sheet you specified.
```

Comment: Tried and still gives me data on the first sheet. Is this something to do with excel?

Comment: I edited my answer check if that works for you, otherwise, to be honest i can't answer that question without a look on your excel file, i would suggest you copy the data from the sheet you want, to a separate excel file (copy it to the first sheet) and just read it using pandas.

Comment: Hi. What information would you require from excel. I can share an image to this question.

Comment: try the updated answer

Comment: It returns with a key error for the 2nd solution.

Comment: copying data from one excel to another excel is a manual task as I need to capture information of 90 days(90 excels) to be sorted to another one excel with dates.